# react-testing-library, check if component method was called

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

Using `'@testing-library/react'`,

given the following component:

```
const Home = () => {
   const submit = () => console.log('submit clicked');

   return (
     <div>
       Home
      <Button
        onClick={submit}
      >
        Submit
      </Button>
     </div>
   )
}
```

What assertion is necessary to add in order to finish the test below?

```
it('reacts to a submit event', async () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<Home />);

    fireEvent.click(getByText(/submit/i));
  })
```

Comment: Your `const submit = () => console.log('submit clicked');` is inside `Home` function which makes it a closed scope inaccessible function. First you should try to remove it outside of it and then you can possibly export the function and then import that in your test, attach a spy on that and see if it was called.

Comment: Alternatively you may check for some DOM text change to see if the click went through.

Comment: I agree with @Rikin, don't check if the method has been called. When it gets called something will happen and the page will change. Check that the changes happen

Answer (score 1):

I need to get this out of the way: [Testing Library's Guiding Principles](https://testing-library.com/docs/guiding-principles/) consider testing implementation details, like asserting on whether a specific internal function was called or not, to be a bad pattern:

> The more your tests resemble the way your software is used, the more
> confidence they can give you.

As written, your component's `submit` function is an implementation detail.  The consumer doesn't know how the submit button is implemented, but they can expect the button to be rendered and clickable.  There's just no indication of what should happen.

I prefer to assert the effect of a button click on the DOM, but if logging to console is all we have, you can spy on `console.log`:

```
test('logs something to the console when submit is clicked', () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
  render(<Home />);
  
  const submitButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: /submit/i });
  fireEvent.click(submitButton);

  expect(spy ).toHaveBeenCalledWith('submit clicked');
});
```

So, we can do this, but I really urge you to think about whether we should.  It really feels like testing implementation details, which results in brittle tests.  Brittle tests tend to break when implementation details change.  Tests that break when the user's experience hasn't is an indication that the test is worthless.  A good test should provide confidence that your software works as the user expects.

Now, all of this doesn't mean that you shouldn't test the component's API.  If your component was adjusted to accept a function that would be called when the `Submit` button is clicked, it would be fine to render it with a mock, simulate the button click, and assert that it works as the consumer expects:

```
test('calls the provided submit function', () => {
  const submit = jest.fn();
  render(<Home submit={submit} />);
  
  const submitButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: /submit/i });
  fireEvent.click(submitButton);

  expect(submit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```